# How to install Ionic2 locally in ubuntu?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I can not install Ionic globally because I have different projects and need to transition between different versions, but I can not find information on how to install with npm without sudo and -g, has anyone done this yet?

Comment: you mean you need to install different ionic cli versions on the same system?

Answer (score 0):

You can install it globally and use the

```
ionic start appName --v2
```

multiple times with multiple projects.

For instance,

```
D:/Apps/App A
D:/Apps/App B
D:/Apps/App C
```

how many ever applications, you want you can create using the above command.

Installing globally will not make any impact to multiple applications